# Can I ack/nack message after the streaming pull timeout exceeds?

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I am writing a python program using Google CLoud Pub/Sub subscription, following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#python). Now I have the following code.

```py
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(my_credentials)
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(my_project_id, my_subscription_id)
streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(my_subscription_path, my_callback)
with subscriber:
  try:
    streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=100)
  except futures.TimeoutError:
    # Can I ack or nack message here?
    streaming_pull_future.cancel()
    streaming_pull_future.result()
```

So my question is, could I ack or nack message after `streaming_pull_future.result` raises a `futures.TimeoutError` exception?

Comment: Here the 'with' block is used to automatically call close() when done. We are using message.ack() to tell the published message received  successfully. In my opinion, it is better to acknowledge only after the message has been successfully delivered.